# kcfinder + Ckeditor +laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ckeditor

при загрузке изображения пишет нет прав

файл config.php kcfinder

```
$_CONFIG = array(


// GENERAL SETTINGS

    'disabled' => true,
    'uploadURL' => asset('storage/uploads'),
    'uploadDir' => "",
    'theme' => "default",

    'types' => array(

    // (F)CKEditor types
        'files'   =>  "",
        'flash'   =>  "swf",
        'images'  =>  "*img",

    // TinyMCE types
        'file'    =>  "",
        'media'   =>  "swf flv avi mpg mpeg qt mov wmv asf rm",
        'image'   =>  "*img",
    ),


// IMAGE SETTINGS

    'imageDriversPriority' => "imagick gmagick gd",
    'jpegQuality' => 90,
    'thumbsDir' => ".thumbs",

    'maxImageWidth' => 0,
    'maxImageHeight' => 0,

    'thumbWidth' => 100,
    'thumbHeight' => 100,

    'watermark' => "",


// DISABLE / ENABLE SETTINGS

    'denyZipDownload' => false,
    'denyUpdateCheck' => false,
    'denyExtensionRename' => false,


// PERMISSION SETTINGS

    'dirPerms' => 0755,
    'filePerms' => 0644,

    'access' => array(

        'files' => array(
            'upload' => true,
            'delete' => true,
            'copy'   => true,
            'move'   => true,
            'rename' => true
        ),

        'dirs' => array(
            'create' => true,
            'delete' => true,
            'rename' => true
        )
    ),

    'deniedExts' => "exe com msi bat cgi pl php phps phtml php3 php4 php5 php6 py pyc pyo pcgi pcgi3 pcgi4 pcgi5 pchi6",


// MISC SETTINGS

    'filenameChangeChars' => array(/*
        ' ' => "_",
        ':' => "."
    */),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

он же у вас отключен, измените параметр

```
'disabled' => true
```

на false